# How to show loading spinner whenever material table loading

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Hi I am using angular to display a table. I used material table, in order to show a spinner when table is loading, I defined a variable **isLoading**. It works like this:
in ts file:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit{

  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Ticket>();
  isLoading = true;


  constructor(private ticket: TicketService,

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllTicket();

  }


  getAllTicket() {
    this.ticket.getAllTicket(queryParams).then((res: Ticket[]) => {
      this.isLoading = false;
      this.ticketList = res;
      this.originalTicketList = this.ticketList;
      this.dataSource.data = this.ticketList;
    });
  }

  searchTicket() {
    this.getAllTicket();
  }

}
```

and my html like this:

```
<div id="main-body">
  <div class="search-bar">
      <select [(ngModel)]="searchBy" class="border-primary">
        <option value="">-- choose an option--</option>
        <option value="id">SIR ID</option>
      </select>
        <!--   here is the input i type and hit enter to trigger searchTicket() function -->
      <input type="text" class="form-control card border-primary ele fnt"
        placeholder="Enter the SIR ID or Host or sha256 or User ID" aria-label="Ticket Id"
        aria-describedby="button-addon2" [(ngModel)]="currentTicketId" (keyup.enter) = "searchTicket()">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ticket-result">
    <div class="ticket-container">
      <table mat-table matTableExporter [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">
          <!--   my table column definition here -->
      </table>
      <mat-card *ngIf="isLoading" class="mat-card-style">
        <mat-progress-spinner color="primary" mode="indeterminate">
        </mat-progress-spinner>
      </mat-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I defined a isLoading variable, when the data loaded, the loading spinner is shown.  but this only happened when i loading the page. In my html there is an input field, and type something and hit enter, and then trigger **searchTicket()** function. this function also to retrieve data from **getAllTicket()** function.

At this time the isLoading is already false and the spinner would display. So Here how can let the spinner also shown when trigger this **searchTicket()** function??

I tried to add `isLoading=true` in searchTicket() function, but this won't work.

Comment: Sorry, I still didn't get the point. do you mean use getter and setter can fire the ngOnChanges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set it back to `true`

```
searchTicket() {
  this.isLoading = true;
  this.getAllTicket();
}
```